# Put aside down the content

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using the following markup in my main content area:

```
<div class="row">
  <aside class="col-md-3 sidebar col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
      content
  </aside>
  <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
      content
  </div>
</div>
```

But in extra small devices, I would like to put aside bellow the main div. I try to use push and pull but the div moves to the right.

Comment: have you tried with mediaqueries?

Comment: @SHT I tray to change float using MQ with no result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you start with the `aside` underneath, then at larger sizes, the push/pull classes will reverse the order. Like this:

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 col-sm-push-3">
  DIVcontent
  </div>
  <aside class="col-md-3 sidebar col-sm-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-pull-9">
  ASIDEcontent
  </aside>
</div>
```

Comment: +1 Just for using the new code snippet editor :) And it's a good answer too.

Comment: @RobQuincey Haha ty, I've been dying to try it out! Worked really well, kudos to the devs.